# Why does this sentence have "And so it was" at the beginning? | "And so it was that the beggar died."

Tags: sentence-structure, idiomatic-language

**"And so it was that the beggar died and was carried by the angels unto Abraham's bosom."** [Lazarus phenomenon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvFIcMH8B8g) (see:6:28-6:32)

Why does the sentence start with **"And so it was that ......."?** when it simply meant **"The beggar died and was carried ......"**?

Is this a literary usage?

Comment: Biblical Hebrew used a single letter to mean "and" with the same letter forming a formal past-tense verb. It means only one or the other, but is often used as though it means both. So many sentences start with "And" without meaning that at all.

Comment: This is Biblical translation. See all the versions: https://biblehub.com/luke/16-22.htm It means: And then what happened was x.

Comment: In most contexts I would understand the formula as meaning “And that is how (or why) …”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"And so it was that..." is used to transition between sentences, usually indicating the passage of time. However, you do not hear this phrasing outside of a historical narrative. If you spoke like this, [you would sound like a Tolkein character](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077869/quotes/?item=qt2692677&ref_=ext_shr_lnk).

Note that there are [other translations of the same verse](https://biblehub.com/luke/16-22.htm) that suggest more modern phrasing that function the same such as "One day the beggar died...".